# Is there no "Remove Widget" functionality in VSCode, for Flutter?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

When I press Cmd + . in VSCode I get various options to add various Widgets to my Widget tree.

But I also find it quite handy to be able to remove a widget by a single action from that Widget tree.

But when I press Cmd + . I do not see any "Remove Widget" option.

Is it not there?
Can I get that functionality?

Comment: You actually have that feature in `Cmd` + `.` but depends if the widget tree or that specific widget is properly structure from the parent down to the child/ren.

Comment: Yeah, I have discovered the "Remove this widget", sometimes when I press Cmd + . - Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the keybinding of `Refactor` command

[image: ss1]

As you see on `SizedBox` you see the remove option.

[image]

Comment: Ah yeah I see that. On this particular Mac the shortcut is: Ctrl + Shift + R - Thank you folks!